Excel to produce "tree" tables
I am new working with Excel data models, and I would like to know if is possible to do the following:

I have a table that lists elements by boxes. Box type 1 contains elements 1,2,3,4: box type 2 contains elements 2,5,7,9; Box type 3 contains elements 2,4,6: Box type n contains elements…..
I went in the warehouse, and I counted the quantity of boxes that I saw and listed all of them.
I need to know how many elements 1, 2, 3 … n I have.

I tried to indicate with the tables in the attached image.
Is it possible to generate with a pivot table the report that says: element 1 – 24 units: element 2 – 21 units and so on.
I appreciate your help.
Regards,
As suggested, I included the tables in the a better format. I included also an image trying to explain what I need.
I appreciate any help



Box Type
Element inside the box
Quantity of elements




1
Element 1
2


1
Element 2
4


1
Element 3
6


2
Element 4
1


2
Element 1
3


2
Element 3
5


3
Element 1
1


3
Element 5
2


3
Element 6
3


4
Element 1
4


4
Element 2
5






Box ID
Box type




A01
1


A02
2


A03
1


B01
2


C01
3


D01
4



The expected report as result is:



Elements
Total elements




Element 1
15


Element   2
13


Element 3
22


Element   4
2


Element 5
2


Element   6
3




My approximation to the data model (I don't know if it's right)


A solution for this problem would be using SUMIFS: https://i.sstatic.net/P58ia.png  the formula used in cell C21 is =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$12;$A$2:$A$12;$B21;$B$2:$B$12;C$20) then just drag down and to right and sum up each column

Great idea Foxfire. Any guess with data Model? My goal is to simplify as much as possible the file

As posted in the comments, you can do this easily and fast with SUMIFS:

Cells A1:C12 would be your input. It's a copy of your provided input. Same for cells A20:B26.
The only thing I did was manually typing Element 1 in cell C20 and then drag to right until cell H20.
Then formula in cell C21 is:
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$12;$A$2:$A$12;$B21;$B$2:$B$12;C$20)

Just drag formula to right and down to get your desired output.
It takes seconds to do this but just in case you got Excel 365 probably you could get elements headers with a formula like =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B1:B12) but not tested.

Hello Foxfire. The answer is a very clever solution. I would like to work the problem like data modeling and try to create a report with pivot tables. I attached a picture of the datamodel that I reckon can model the problem, but I do not how to generate the report. I appreciate any idea.

@El-VeRdUgO Then use the right tags. Edit your question properly and specify you want a Power Pivot solution only. Use the tag Power Pivot, right now your question is missing that one.
